# Probability in permutation of balls

Tags: probability, permutations, law-of-large-numbers, balls-in-bins

There are $n$ balls, of which $r$ balls are red  and $(n-r)$ balls are blue.

If we select $d$ balls at random (without replacement), what is the probability we select $rd/n$ red balls? In the asymptotic case, can we show concentration around $rd/n$?

Comment: Have you tried to evaluate cases where r and n are small? It hurts me when people not even try something.

Comment: unless $n$ divides $rd$, the probability you select $\frac{rd}{n}$ balls will be $0$ even though that is the expected number selected

Answer (score 0):

The expectation for the amount red balls in $n$ can be found:

$$\begin{align} 
E(r) &= \dfrac{n}{2} \\ \\
E(d) &= \dfrac{n}{2} \\ \\
E(d=r) &= \frac{\frac{n}{2}}{2} = \frac{n}{4} \\
\end{align}$$

Then $$E\left(\dfrac{rd}{n}\right) = \dfrac{E(r) * E(d)}{n} = \dfrac{\frac{n}{2}*\frac{n}{2}}{n} = \dfrac{\frac{n^2}{4}}{n} = \frac{n}{4}$$